# gmaps.js displays coordinates instead of address when I click 'Get Directions'

Tags: javascript, jquery, gmaps.js

After searching for hours, I've come to the conclusion that I have to integrate reverse geocoding. However, I'm not sure how to integrate it into the gmaps.js. What I'm trying to accomplish is displaying the address instead of coordinates(lang,long) when the user clicks on "get directions"

```
<script>
 var pinsPath = 'http://www.bohlerengineering.com/wp-content/themes/bohler/img/pins_map/';
 var locations = new Array();
 $(document).ready(function() {

 console.log(locations);
 placeMarkers(locations, false);

 $('.locationButton').click(function(e){
  $this=$(this);
  currentId = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
  google.maps.event.trigger(mapsHelper.markers[currentId], 'click');
  //mapsHelper.infoBubbles[currentId].open();

  /** Forma anterior
  mapsHelper.removeMarkers();
  //mapsHelper.placeMarkerByAddress($(this).attr('rel'), function(lat, lng){
  placeMarkers({'0': locations[$(this).attr('rel')]}, true); **/
  e.preventDefault();
});

function placeMarkers(locations, popWindow){
  for(key in locations){
    var pinPath = pinsPath+locations[key]['state_abbrev'].toLowerCase()+'.png'
    if(locations[key]['lat'] && locations[key]['lng']){
      console.log('KEY COORD: '+key);
      console.log('placed marker by coords');

      var marker = mapsHelper.placeMarker(locations[key]['lat'], locations[key]['lng'], pinPath, locations[key]['id']);
      //infoWindow = mapsHelper.addInfoWindow(marker, $('#info-'+locations[key]['id']).html());
      infoBubble = mapsHelper.addInfoBubble(marker, $('#info-'+locations[key]['id']).html(), function(){
  //            setTimeout(function(){
//              $('img[src="http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/iw_close.gif"]').attr('src', '/wp-content/themes/streetsenseV2/img/cruz_nav_active.png');
//            }, 300);
      });
      if(popWindow){ 
        console.log('Pop window!');
        console.log(mapsHelper.map);
        infoWindow.open(mapsHelper.map, marker);
      }
    }else{
      console.log('KEY: '+key);
      console.log('ID: '+locations[key]['id']);
      mapsHelper.placeMarkerByAddress(locations[key]['rel'], key, pinPath, function(lat, lng, marker, key){
        //console.log(locations);
        console.log('KEY INSIDE: '+key);
        //infoWindow = mapsHelper.addInfoWindow(marker, $('#info-'+locations[key]['id']).html());
        infoBubble = mapsHelper.addInfoBubble(marker, $('#info-'+locations[key]['id']).html(), locations[key]['id'], function(){
  //              setTimeout(function(){
  //                $('img[src="http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/iw_close.gif"]').attr('src', '/wp-content/themes/streetsenseV2/img/cruz_nav_active.png');
  //              }, 300);
        });
        //if(popWindow) infoWindow.open(mapsHelper.map, marker);
        if(popWindow) infoBubble.open(mapsHelper.map, marker);
        console.log('Save location coords: '+locations[key]['id']);
        $.get('/wp-content/themes/bohler/ajax/locate.php?id='+locations[key]['id']+'&lat='+lat+'&lng='+lng);
      });
    }
  }
  }
  })
  </script>
```

Here's the site I'm working on. When you click on a icon on a location, it should display 'get directions. When I click on that it sends me to a different page that displays the directions by coordinates(longitude,latitude) instead of address.
http://www.bohlereng.com/locations/